# Understanding RBENV: Switching Ruby Versions Locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

After upgrading my Ruby version, I've (as expected) run in to some trouble getting my server up and running with older projects. I'm curious about how to switch Ruby versions locally for a specific project.  Rbenv's github page uses `$ rbenv local 1.9.3-p327`as an example command of how to do this.  What I want to know is what the `-p327` refers to, what it should be in my case, and if it's even necessary.  Can I just run `$ rbenv local 2.3.1` for example?

(In my case, I am currently using Ruby -v 2.4.0 want to go back to an earlier version to avoid a Devise Gem error that I can't seem to get past.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your other question,

> Rbenv's github page uses `$ rbenv local 1.9.3-p327` as an example command of how to do this. What I want to know is what the `-p327` refers to...

The old versioning policy for Ruby was `MAJOR`.`MINOR`.`TEENY`-`PATCH`

`p327` simply refers to patchlevel, which is basically a number that gets incremented for each accepted patch after the increment of a `MINOR` number. [Prior to Ruby 2.1](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/), security fixes did not increment the `TEENY` version, so some releases specify the patchlevel.

Comment: Ahh... that explains it!  So not necessarily necessary when switching versions.  Is it good practice to keep track & use the latest patchlevels when switching versions then?  Thanks Adam.

Comment: @BrandonElder generally you want to target a `MINOR` version, e.g. `2.3`, and then there is usually some wiggle room with the `TEENY` version. Some production environments are more strict, so YMMV. If in doubt, choose whatever version is running in production. Since the policy change for 2.1 I linked, you won't see a separate patchlevel number in a release.

Answer (score 2):

`$ rbenv local 2.3.1` will do exactly as you surmised. The project specific version of Ruby is set via a `.ruby-version` file in the project directory. This setting takes precedence over any use of `rbenv global` that would set the Ruby version where otherwise unspecified.

Comment: You answered like 13 seconds earlier to me ;)

Comment: Ok...great, and thanks for the response.  I guess my only confusion now is that I don't seem to have a file named `.ruby_version` in my project directory.  Where would I find this and might it be named something else?

Comment: That's `.ruby-version` not `.ruby_version`

Answer (score 1):

**Rbenv uses a file .ruby-version to detect the ruby version project is using**. So are you having that file?

Based on the version of the ruby your project uses, just write a number in your file.

example: `2.3.0`

Comment: Ah, didn't notice your response...thank you.  As I commented to @MarsAtomic, I don't seem to have a file named `.ruby_version`.  I'm wondering why I wouldn't have that in my project?

Comment: Well, if you don't find it, just create one in the same hierarchy as .git :) and the content of the file should be the version of the ruby the project is using @BrandonElder